# Как сохранить пропорции кнопки при изменении высоты и ширины?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

При изменении высоты окна, кнопка меню навигации становится 
 непропорциональной и растянутой.
 Как это исправить?

Изобржение с проблемой прилагается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
/*ЛЕВОЕ МЕНЮ*/
/*ЛЕВОЕ МЕНЮ*/
.spisok {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #7B2019;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*border*/
  border-top: 1.6vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 2vh solid #000;
  border-left: 1.5vh solid #000;
  border-right: 0vh solid #000;
  /*border ends*/
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.spisok li {
  width: 24vh;
  list-style-image: none;
  height: 5.5vh;
  background-image: url(https://ibb.co/xsRFz4L);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: center no-repeat;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 0.45vh;
}

#oblacheniya {
  
}
.spisok li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.05vh;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2vh;
  font-weight: normal;
  }

.spisok ul>li:hover {
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu_hover.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: center no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spisok ul li>a:hover {
  text-shadow: gold 0 0 4vh;
  /* Свечение голубого цвета */
  color: white;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 0vh;
}
.button.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 0vh;
}
.spisok ul {
  list-style-image: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;

}
.spisok ul li a p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#ugol {
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu_black.png);
}

.text-div {
  width: 15.8vh;
  height: 3vh;
}

.letter-spacing {
  letter-spacing: 0.1vh;
}

.ryasi {
  letter-spacing: 0.2vh;
}
```

```html
  <nav id="leftmenu-wrapper">
   <div class="spisok">
    <ul class="button.block">
     <li><a class="text-div" id="oblacheniya" href="/left_menu/oblacheniya/oblacheniya-type-select.php">  <p><span class="letter-spacing">Облачения</span></p></a>
     </li>
     <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/podrizniki.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing">Подризники</span></p></a></li>
     <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/stihari.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing">Стихари</span></p></a></li>
     <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/ryasi.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing, ryasi">Рясы</span></p></a></li>
     <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/podryasniki.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing">Подрясники</span></p></a></li>
     <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/golovniye_ubori.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing">Головные уборы</span></p></a></li>
     <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/for_monahov.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing">Для монахов</span></p></a></li>
     <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/kresh_nabory.php"><p>Крещальные наборы</p></a></li>
     <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/vench_nabory.php"><p>Венчальные наборы</p></a></li>
     <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/obl_for_hrama.php"><p>Облачения для храма</p></a></li>
     <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/vishitiye_kresty.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing">Вышитые кресты</span></p></a></li>
     <li id="ugol"><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/ugol.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing">Кадильный уголь</span></p></a></li>
    </ul> 
   </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: всё выглядит хорошо - вопрос не ясен

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, спасибо за Ваще внимание к этому вопросу. Обратите внимание на болтики по углам.

Comment: болтиков нету в снипете по углам

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский почему-то не грузится фотография, которая является кнопкой

Comment: на stackimgur загружайте картинку и ставьте на фон

Comment: Судя по изображению - можно с Божьей помощью попробовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как например, немножко исправила Ваш `html` (в тег `a` не желательно вставлять тег `p`, `button.block` - не валидное имя класса, лучше точку заменить на дефис) и `css`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/*ЛЕВОЕ МЕНЮ*/

.spisok {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  /* width: 20%; */
  background-color: #7B2019;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  border-top: 1.6vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 2vh solid #000;
  border-left: 1.5vh solid #000;
  border-right: 0vh solid #000;
}

.button-block {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.spisok li {   
  margin-top: 0.45vh;
}

.spisok li a {
  display: block;
  width: 24vh;
  height: 5.5vh;
  line-height: 4.5vh;
  font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.05vh;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2vh;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: #a1392e;
  border-radius: .5vw;
  padding: .5vh .5vw;
  
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spisok li a:hover {
  background: #884111;
}

#ugol a {
  background: #000;
}

.spisok li a>span {
  display: block;
}


.spisok li a>span:before,
.spisok li a>span:after,
.spisok li a:before,
.spisok li a:after {
  content:'';
  width: 1vh;
  height: 1vh;
  background: url(https://cdn130.picsart.com/262053088007211.png?r1024x1024) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: .5vh;
}

.spisok li a>span:before,
.spisok li a>span:after {
  bottom: .5vh;
  top:auto;
}

.spisok li a>span:before,
.spisok li a:before {
  left: .5vw;
}

.spisok li a>span:after,
.spisok li a:after {
  right: .5vw;
}



.spisok ul li>a:hover {
  text-shadow: gold 0 0 4vh;
  color: white;
}


.spisok ul {
  list-style-image: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;

}


#ugol {
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu_black.png);
}

.text-div {
  width: 15.8vh;
  height: 3vh;
}
```

```html
<nav id="leftmenu-wrapper">
  <div class="spisok">
    <ul class="button-block">
      <li><a class="text-div" id="oblacheniya" href="/left_menu/oblacheniya/oblacheniya-type-select.php"><span >Облачения</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/podrizniki.php"><span>Подризники</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/stihari.php"><span>Стихари</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/ryasi.php"><span>Рясы</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/podryasniki.php"><span >Подрясники</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/golovniye_ubori.php"><span >Головные уборы</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/for_monahov.php"><span >Для монахов</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/kresh_nabory.php"><span>Крещальные наборы</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/vench_nabory.php"><span>Венчальные наборы</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/obl_for_hrama.php"><span>Облачения для храма</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/vishitiye_kresty.php"><span >Вышитые кресты</span></a></li>
      <li id="ugol"><a class="text-div" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/left_menu/ugol.php"><span >Кадильный уголь</span></a></li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
</nav>
```